# Trying to loop up and down directories for my bot program but struggling with it

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, directory, tweepy

Ok so a bit of introduction. I am trying to create a bot that scrapes the images and posts of reddit and tweets them out. This is not my full project but its pretty much all the relevant stuff.

So the thing is I need to download the images into a directory and ive called that directory 'pics' but I also need to log the reddit post ID's (which I do with a different function not displayed here) into a text file and I need to read through it to check if its already been tweeted. This is what the already_tweeted function does.

Here is the problem, on my first loop, It will read through the file (which is empty at the moment) and then move on to using the get_image funcition. I need to change the current directory to the image directory so I can store the images which I do (os.chdir(img_dir)). Now the directory is changed and when I go back to read the oldies.txt file it says it doesnt exist since It is in the original directory and not the pics directory.

So What I need to do is go up to the original directory after I have downloaded the images into the 'pics' directory and I am completely stuck on that.

```
import time
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import praw
import tweepy

def tweet_creator(subreddit_info):
    '''Goes through posts on reddit and extracts a shortened link, title & ID'''
    post_links = [] #list to store our links
    post_titles = [] #list to store our titles
    post_ids = [] #list to store our id's
    post_imgs = []
    print("[bot] extracting posts from sub-reddit")

    for submission in subreddit_info.new(limit=5):
        if not already_tweeted(submission.id):
            post_titles.append(submission.title)
            post_links.append(submission.shortlink)
            post_ids.append(submission.id)
            post_imgs = get_image(submission.url)
            print(post_imgs)

        else:
            print("Already Tweeted")
    return post_links, post_titles, post_ids, post_imgs

def already_tweeted(post_id):
    '''reads through our .txt file and determines if tweet has already been posted'''
    found = 0

    print(os.getcwd())
    with open(posted_reddit_ids, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if post_id in line:
                found = 1
                break
    return found

def get_image(img_url):
    url = img_url
    r = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent' : 'reddit Twitter tool monitoring (by /u/RivianJourneyMan)'})
    data = r.text
    soup = bs(data, 'lxml')

    image_tags = soup.findAll('img')

    os.chdir(img_dir)
    x = 0
    mylist = []
    for image in image_tags:
            url = image['src']
            source = requests.get(url, stream = True)
            if source.status_code == 200:
                img_file = img_dir + str(x) + '.jpg'
                with open(img_file, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(requests.get(url).content)
                    mylist.append(img_file)
                    f.close()
                    x += 1
                    return img_file
            else:
                mylist.append(None)
    return mylist
```

Once again this is not my full code, only the relevant parts but this is what it outputs when I run it. As you can see in the alread_tweated function, I asked it to print out what directory I am in as I am looping to make it easier to see the problem.

```
[bot] Setting up connection with reddit
[bot] extracting posts from sub-reddit
C:\Users\ali\PycharmProjects\cyberbot
pics0.jpg
C:\Users\ali\PycharmProjects\cyberbot\pics
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ali/PycharmProjects/cyberbot/rtbot_with_img2.py", line 154, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/ali/PycharmProjects/cyberbot/rtbot_with_img2.py", line 150, in main
    post_links, post_titles, post_ids, post_imgs = tweet_creator(subreddit)
  File "C:/Users/ali/PycharmProjects/cyberbot/rtbot_with_img2.py", line 58, in tweet_creator
    if not already_tweeted(submission.id):
  File "C:/Users/ali/PycharmProjects/cyberbot/rtbot_with_img2.py", line 81, in already_tweeted
    with open(posted_reddit_ids, 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'oldies.txt'
```

Now I have been looking everywhere and trying as many solutions to go back to the original directory but none of them work. I've tried os.chdir('..') and I put it just above the 'return mylist[]' but that didn't work. I pretty much want to go into the 'pics' directory to download my images and then I want to go back to my original directory which is the 'cyberbot' one so that I can read through my oldies.txt file to see if I already tweeted the post

[Perhaps this picture of how my directories and files will help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YMKG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**NB:** There are two ways to solve this.

**PS:** The `os.chdir('..')` should work

**1)** Get the path of pics and oldies.txt directories

```
img_dir = "/Users/ali/PycharmProjects/cyberbot/pics"
oldies_dir = "/Users/ali/PycharmProjects/cyberbot"

def already_tweeted(post_id):
    # begin by changing the directory first
    os.chdir(oldies_dir)
    ...

def get_image(image_url):
    os.chdir(img_dir)
    ...
```

**2)** If you know the full path of the oldies.txt, you could set it as follows, however, I haven't used windows much but i know the path syntax to a file differs from unix.

```
posted_reddit_ids = "/full_path_of_file/oldies.txt"
```

This will allow your file to be read anywhere from within the code no matter how many times you change directories